# Is there any way to "stretch" a given colormap for a larger range?

Tags: matlab, colormap

I'm building a MATLAB program to visualize a simulation of particles clustering.
Our simulation usually runs with around 10000 particles and the clusters might get to be around 5000 particles in size and I wanted to color the clusters by size so i inserted the following code:

```
a=[1 1 1 500]; %means x=1 y=1 z=1 and clustersize=500
colormap(flipud(pink));
scatter3(a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3),repmat(10,numel(a(:,1)),1),a(:,4),'filled','MarkerEdgeColor', 'k')
```

and after a cluster reaches a certain size it becomes "saturated" and sticks with the same color even when growing to be twice that size. 
I've tried using `colormap(hsv(1024));` to make a larger color map but that isn't very good for me either since i want to use a uniform gradient from light to dark and now necessarily mess around with lots of various colors, as the aren't distinguishable enough.

Any ideas how to stretch `colormap(flipud(pink));` so it'll get saturated only around 5000? or alternatively let me know if there is some other solution that'll give me a higher "dynamic range"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Do you want to _add_ or _remove_ the saturation effect?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've managed to find the solution whilst trying to figure out how to explain the problem better, funny how it works out =]
Since I'm new to this site, is there any option of marking the question answered?

Comment: Yes, you can accept (tick mark on the upper left) your own answer. It will benefit future readers, and remove the question from the "unanswered" list. I would only suggest that you explain your question and answer better; I still don't get exactly what you wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so while trying to answer Luis Mendo I started making a gif of the simulation, and decided to add a `colorbar;` to the figure, then I saw that the colorbar stretched itself from figure to figure.
I found the code

```
lowrange = 1;
highrange = 5000;
caxis manual
caxis([lowrange highrange]);
```

which I used earlier for another simulation worked to predetermine the `colorbar;`'s range. this apparently meant the range of the colormap was also "stretched" or used the predetermined range.

Here are two clips from the simulation, one with the `caxis` fix, and one without, notice how the colorbar changes without the fix, that caused the particles to loop black(saturated) the for most of the simulation, regardless of the cluster size.

[simulation without the corrected caxis code](http://youtu.be/DaYKqznrE3U)

[simulation with corrected caxis code](http://youtu.be/oRoKdraAd8I)